# How do you view real time browser memory usage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ie11-developer-tools

I have a Javascript heavy application that uses Angular 1.3

In Chrome it (typically) runs just fine, but when I load the same page in IE11 and view CPU and Memory in Windows task manager, the CPU is at 95% and Memory around 200MB! This is just a simple page sat there idle with no user interaction. If I open multiple tabs IE11 is just killed and hangs.

In FireFox its at 5% CPU, 280MB.

The same page in Chrome is 1% CPU, and just 40MB Memory.

I've downloaded FireFox and installed FireBug - what's the best way for me to see what is consuming this memory and CPU usage in IE.

Many thanks.

Comment: It turns out that a third party script uses listeners to dynamically position elements on the screen sending over 4000 poll requests a minute! Lesson: don't expect much from OTS scripts for free!